# Django + Nginx + Uwsgi 80 порт отдает стартовую страницу Nginx

Tags: django, nginx, uwsgi

У мен есть приложение в связке Django + Nginx + Uwsgi. Nginx работает на 80 порту, приложение Django на 8000 (по дефолту)

*Symlink nginx config*

```
# the upstream component nginx needs to connect to
upstream django {
    server unix:///root/ubergf/client/uwsgi_nginx.sock; # for a file socket
    # server 127.0.0.1:8001; # for a web port socket (we'll use this first)
}

# configuration of the server
server {
    # the port your site will be served on
    listen      80;
    # the domain name it will serve for
    server_name my-site.com; # substitute your machine's IP address or FQDN
    charset     utf-8;

    # max upload size
    client_max_body_size 75M;   # adjust to taste

    # Django media
    location /media  {
    alias /root/ubergf/client/media;  # your Django project's media files - amend as required
    }

    location /static {
    alias /root/ubergf/client/staticfiles; # your Django project's static files - amend as required
    }

    # Finally, send all non-media requests to the Django server.
    location / {
    uwsgi_pass  django;
    include     /root/ubergf/client/deployment/uwsgi_params; # the uwsgi_params file you installed
    }
}
```

*uwsgi_params*

```
uwsgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
uwsgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
uwsgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
uwsgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;

uwsgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
uwsgi_param  PATH_INFO          $document_uri;
uwsgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
uwsgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;
uwsgi_param  REQUEST_SCHEME     $scheme;
uwsgi_param  HTTPS              $https if_not_empty;

uwsgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
uwsgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
uwsgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
uwsgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;
```

*ubergfapi_uwsgi.ini*

```
[uwsgi]

chdir           = /root/ubergf/client
module          = ubergfapi.wsgi
master          = true
processes       = 10
socket          = /root/ubergf/client/uwsgi_nginx.sock
chmod-socket    = 666
vacuum          = true
env             = DEBUG_MODE=False
```

Когда я запускаю приложение на 8000 порту my_domain:8000 (меняю настройку в конфиге nginx) у меня все работает, но когда я ставлю *listen 80* my_domain отдает мне стартовую страницу Nginx, хотя я ожидаю страницу своего приложения.

я так же пробывал добавлять к конфигу следующие параметры

```
proxy_pass http://your_server_ip:8000;
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
```

Но все равно при обращении к my_domain получаю стартовую страницу Nginx.

Comment: @andreymal Про что конкретно вы говорите? У меня указан     server_name my-site.com; в секции server

Answer (score 0):

Я добавил

```
uwsgi_param Host $host;
uwsgi_param X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
uwsgi_param X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
uwsgi_param X-Forwarded-Proto $http_x_forwarded_proto;
```

в секцию `location` и все заработало